# What is the precision of the timestamp field in a druid datastore?

Tags: druid, nosql

A druid entry has a timestamp, dimension(s) and metric(s).

An example (from the website) of an ingested entry (CSV):

```
2013-08-31T01:02:33Z,"f7ehv","AHX","true",57,200,-143
```

I have a bunch of readings taken by a single node in rapid succession. It logs the data with nanosecond precision. My question is, "*Can druid handle nanosecond precision for timestamps?*".

These don't have to processed in real time, the ingestion into the database can be balanced w.r.t. the load on the server. And queries will not be an issue.

I would appreciate a link to the specification/documentation regarding timestamps.
I have looked at the [documentation](http://druid.io/docs/0.9.2/design/index.html) but could not find anything specific to this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Druid ingests timestamps in millisecond precision. It's not super clear, but you can infer it from their Ingestion Spec doc and the Granularity doc:

> timestamp format: iso, millis, posix, auto or any Joda time format

http://druid.io/docs/latest/ingestion/#timestampspec

> query granularity: minimum here is none which means millisecond granularity

http://druid.io/docs/latest/querying/granularities.html

I also found this link in the Google Groups:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/druid-user/2oAq41dCGbg

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thanks, this is essentially what I was looking for. Might consider storing the < second precision as an int in another field. That might solve the problem.

Comment: Looking at the recent documentation it seems that druid now supports timestamps up to nanosecond precision.